# How to make Bootstrap dropdown-item as hyperlink

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I tried the following example from Bootstrap official website with alpha version Bootstrap 4. But the dropdown-item are not like hyperlinks:

```
<div class="dropdown open">
            <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Dropdown
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I tried adding the classes `disabled` or `btn-link` into the dropdown-item but items still don't appear as links. I'm looking for a solution **without** `JavaScript`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the below `CSS`, then it will look like `hyperlinks`.

```
.dropdown-item{
   color:blue;
   text-decoration:underline;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. I implemented your suggestion in the `.dropdown-menu > li > a {....}` class of `Bootstrap.css`. It works.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Bootstrap's strict Mobile Friendly Philosophy. There is no easy way to do this. Especially without using Javascript.

Most Sites using Bootstrap 3.0 used their own Menu system, rather than the Bootstrap menu. Firstly, because of unclickable parent menu items. And only support for 1 level of dropdown.

Try this anyway!
Replace `button` with `a` tags. And Enclose the entire Dropdown in `li` or any other tag.

```
<div class="dropdown open"><li>
        <a class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div></li>
    </div>
```

And add the corresponding CSS.

```
.dropdown-menu { display: none; }
.dropdown li:hover .dropdown-menu { display: block; }
```

This is not the exact code which would work for your requirements, but I hope you get the idea.